# How to get image type in nvarchar to be executed in exec/sp_execute command

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #T(I IMAGE)

INSERT INTO #T 
VALUES(CAST(N'CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
                  @I IMAGE
              AS
              BEGIN
                  SELECT ''下些''
              END' AS VARBINARY(MAX)))

DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @S = (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(CAST(I AS varbinary(MAX)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
          FROM #T)

EXEC (@S)

DROP TABLE #T
```

I want to put stored procedure's SQL statements into an `image` column, then I want to get the text and execute them in database.

Is conversion and execution correct? That is, is there any thing I am missing?

Should I use `sp_execute` instead of `EXEC`? I noticed I do not have any params.

We are planning to change `image` type but for now, this is the option.

Comment: Why are you creating a temp table that contains create procedure statement? Your question doesn't really explain what you're trying to do here.

Comment: If you want to store **text** (SQL statements) - why on earth are you picking a **deprecated** binary type like `image`?? Make no sense at all - use `varchar(max)` from the beginning and you don't need any messy and error prone conversions at all ......

Comment: it is not temp table , it is permanenet table. and as far as image type is concern , for time begin we are forced to use it.i will change it latter.

Comment: and tables are old i can not change them on the fly. at least technically u people can answer.